# Capture and analyze data from a game in real time

Tags: python

I would like to try to build my own "experience per hour" calculator to an online game I'm playing.

Is it possible to get Python to read/analyze a specific set of numbers from the game without injecting anything (using a bot) and then displaying how much that experience is changing/hour as well as count the total experience gained in that session?

[image]

Sorry about the lack of information and knowledge from my side. I'm very new and just want to know where to start and if python is even the right way to go or not.

It's a relative small online game called [Medivia Online](https://medivia.online/).

I want to read and display how much my experience is changing per hour and total change over a different period of time (current session, last day, 2 days etc)

//BaconBro

Comment: Is it an on-line game? Most of those have a public API that can be used to get a lot of in-game information and then play with it in python.

Comment: Can you add more information? like link to the game, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Found a Python API for this particular game: https://github.com/Ethaan/medivia-python-api. Check it out, I think from looking at the code, it can get the information you need.

Comment: Those are unofficial API which scrape information from the game's website. This will probably lead to get delayed character's info such as the experience gained in a particular period of time. This is just a thought, it depends on how often they update the data. Also it'll stop working if the website changes even a simple html tag.

Comment: I think you're right that looks like the API to generate this website https://mediviastats.info/

The information I'm looking for must be directly from the client to get accurate/realtime information.

Comment: I doubt there's an easier way than grabbing the area of the screen with the information and performing OCR on it to extract the value.